Build version css not work in product version next js 14.2.3
i use nextjs 14.1.3 and mantine componnents in my project and project work fine, but after update my nextjs version to 14.2.3 my styles not work in build wersion but when i use the dev mod everyting is ok. can help me to fix this issue?
command for update: npm i next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest eslint-config-next@latest
